# PairedDelimiter with natural sub- and super-scripts

Tags: math-operators, delimiters

I would like to declare a paired delimiter so that I can use something like the following syntax:

```
\mycommand'_k[\big]{x}\\
\mycommand^\prime_k[\big]{x}
```

to put `x` in parentheses of `\big` size, preceded by a `DeclareMathOperator`, e.g., it would return the equivalent of

```
\texttt{mean}'_k\big(x\big)
```

For example:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\mean}{\texttt{mean}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\mycommand[1]{\operatorname{\mean}}[]{}{#1}%
```

but then I don't know how to provide sub- and super-scripts to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`e` and `t` argument types can be used here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\meanb{[}{]}
\NewDocumentCommand\mycommand{t{'}e{_^}}{%
\operatorname{mean}%
\IfBooleanT{#1}{'}%
\IfNoValueF{#2}{_{#2}}%
\IfNoValueF{#3}{^{#3}}%
\meanb}

\begin{document}


\begin{gather}
\meanb{x}\\
\meanb[\bigg]{x}\\
\mycommand{x} \\
\mycommand^{\prime}{x} \\
\mycommand^{\prime}_{k}{x} \\
\mycommand'{x} \\
\mycommand'_{k}{x} \\
\mycommand[\bigg]{x} \\
\mycommand^{\prime}[\bigg]{x} \\
\mycommand^{\prime}_{k}[\bigg]{x} \\ 
\mycommand'[\bigg]{x} \\
\mycommand'_{k}[\bigg]{x}  
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```